# Is it possible to save a div in session storage and retrieve/append it?

Tags: javascript, html, session-storage

I am making a website which creates some divs when a form is submitted, the problem is that these divs disappear when the form is resubmitted. Would it be possible to save these divs in sessionStorage so that when the form is resubmitted they can be appended back where they were? Something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i <= children.length - 1; i++) {
    var selectedrow = children[i];
    sessionStorage.setItem(i, selectedrow);
}
sessionStorage.setItem('total', children.length)

for (n = 0; n < sessionStorage.getItem('total'); n++) {
    const rowid = sessionStorage.getItem('n');
    selected.appendChild(rowid);
}
```

This code gives the following error
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7DDz.png)

So is there a way I can actually do this?

Comment: For the variable `n` to work I think you need to use string interpolation with ${variable} in backticks: sessionStorage.getItem(`${n}`); But not sure why the code would not work.

Comment: It doesn't work, because what you are reading back from session storage is a mere text, whereas the appendChild method wants a DOM node as argument. You will need to either _create_ DOM nodes from data you have stored (including setting of all attributes, creating and appending of child nodes, etc.) - or use something like innerHTML or outerHTML to create elements from HTML code stored in text form.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [DOMParser()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), this object creates a new DOM document from a string.

To use it, you instantiate a new instance. Then you use the [parseFromString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString) method to convert your string into a new document element. The method accepts the string as it’s first argument. Set the second argument to text/html.

```
var stringToHTML = function (str) {
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
    return doc.body;
};

stringToHTML('<your html returned from session storage>');
```